# How can I add extra option to the dynamic validation list (VBA)?

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I have a table with IDs which are grouped into different groups (one group can include more then 2 elements).

For Column "E" you can select one id from ONLY the related group in every row. Example:

[image]

The code:

```
Sub data_validation()
Dim colNum      As Long
Dim i           As Long
Dim k           As Long

colNum = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Cells.Count
i = 2
Do Until Cells(i, 1) = ""
    k = 0
    Do While Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
       k = k + 1
       i = i + 1
    Loop

    With Range(Cells(i - k, colNum + 2), Cells(i, colNum + 2)).validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=$B$" & i - k & ":$B$" & i
    End With

    i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

How can I add **-** (hyphen) sign to the selection list use with VBA? I have tried with union range, but it has caused type mismatch.

Comment: An easy way would be to use a helper column (e.g. have column G have a formula to concatenate a hyphen and column B), and then have the VBA reference the helper column instead of B.

Comment: You have misunderstood me. I want to choose from the list this [465,234,-] not this [465-,234-]. The hyphen should be the 3th option in the this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you can have for data validation a list that is a union of a range (when I try to do this in Excel not through VBA, the error message is `You may not use reference operators (such as unions, intersections, and ranges) or array constants for Data Validation criteria.`), so it seems to me the best option is to have the list a manual list instead of referring to a range.  You can create such a list with the code below:

```
Sub data_validation()
Dim colNum      As Long
Dim i           As Long
Dim k           As Long
Dim ValidationListFormula As String

colNum = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Cells.Count
i = 2
Do Until Cells(i, 1) = ""
    k = 0
    ValidationListFormula = Cells(i, 2).Value
    Do While Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
       k = k + 1
       i = i + 1
       ValidationListFormula = ValidationListFormula & "," & Cells(i, 2).Value
    Loop

    ValidationListFormula = ValidationListFormula & ",-"
    With Range(Cells(i - k, colNum + 2), Cells(i, colNum + 2)).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=ValidationListFormula
    End With

    i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```